# Orders of objects in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with works fine as shown with the code below, but I would like to change the order of the linear layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".QuickNoteFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <com.RiThBo.noter.ClearableEditText
            android:id="@+id/pn_et_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:hint="@string/qn_et_title_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.RiThBo.noter.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/pn_et_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
        android:hint="@string/qn_et_body_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/pn_cb_ongoing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="99"
            android:text="@string/qn_cb_ongoing" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pn_b_create"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/qn_b_create" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pn_b_getPic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pn_b_getPic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pn_b_takePic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pn_b_takePic" />
    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pn_tv_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pn_tv_preview" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pn_iv_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon" />
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I move the layout with the checkbox and button to the bottom, my app force closes.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:weightSum="100"
        tools:context=".Frag1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

            <com.xxx.xxx.ClearableEditText
                android:id="@+id/pn_et_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
                android:hint="@string/qn_et_title_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.xxx.xxx.ClearableEditText
            android:id="@+id/pn_et_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:hint="@string/qn_et_body_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />       

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pn_b_getPic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pn_b_getPic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pn_b_takePic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pn_b_takePic" />
        </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pn_tv_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/pn_tv_preview" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pn_iv_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon" />
         </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/pn_cb_ongoing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="99"
                android:text="@string/qn_cb_ongoing" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pn_b_create"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/qn_b_create" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea why?

Here is the logcat:

```
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at com.RiThBo.noter.PicNoteFragment.onCreateView(PicNoteFragment.java:75)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1470)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:925)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1458)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:438)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5222)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
07-17 16:32:08.886: E/AndroidRuntime(19192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the onCreateView() for the fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pic_note, container, false);

        mImageBitmap = null;

        b_create = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_b_create);
        b_gallery = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_b_getPic);
        b_camera = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_b_takePic);
        et_body = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_et_body);
        cb_ongoing = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_cb_ongoing);

        et_title = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_et_title);
        et_title.requestFocus();

        s_ticker_text = getString(R.string.ticker_text);
        s_subText = getString(R.string.sub_text);
        s_toastTitleText = getString(R.string.toast_missing_title);

        b_create.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_ongoing.setOnClickListener(this);
        b_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
        b_camera.setOnClickListener(this);

        cb_ongoing.setChecked(false);
        boolean_ongoing = false;

        iv_preview = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pn_iv_preview);
        iv_preview.setImageBitmap(null);
        iv_preview.setClickable(true);
        iv_preview.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootView;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: please post the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: @invertigo  I hope I added the right bit!

Comment: Do you have any code that is calling your xml?

Comment: In your java file you are incorrectly casting a textview to a button.

Comment: @buczek  I am inflating this layout file in a fragment.  It is strange because the first layout works but the second doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** the true fix... do a clean and rebuild and try launching your app again

Based on your stack trace:

`android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`

at

`com.RiThBo.noter.PicNoteFragment.onCreateView(PicNoteFragment.java:75)`

Take a look at the `PicNoteFragment` class, line 75. Or post your code for the onCreateView() and we can help.

Comment: I added the onCreateView().  I think everything is being cast correctly

Comment: do a clean and rebuild and try launching your app again. if it still fails, can you point out in your java snippet which line is #75.

Comment: also, where are you declaring `b_create`, `b_gallery`, and `b_camera`?

Comment: good deal, its amazing how many issues come up because of the lack of a clean

Comment: The build system assigns those id's based on what order they're encountered in the xml files. That's why changing the order messed it up, because until you clean, a full new R.java isn't being generated. So, the id's get swapped up.

Comment: well, typically the R.java gets regenerated (or at least should) if you make any changes to an xml file, but I've seen it not happen before myself. when it doubt, clean it out.

Comment: Thanks Geobits (and invertigo) - I understand how it works now :-)

Comment: if this was the answer that got you to your solution, please mark it as such. thanks :)

Comment: I will, but please edit the answer to just say that you need to clean so that if other people have the same problem, they don't need to read the comments :-).  Thank you again